# Rails 4 - Bootstrap-datepicker - Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I installed the gem.

```
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
```

Added this line to application.css

```
*= require bootstrap-datepicker3
```

Added this line to application.js

```
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

And put this into my form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :start_date %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :start_date, data:{ provide:'datepicker' } %>
</div>
```

It works fine, however I would like to customize the date format, so I changed it to this:

```
<%= f.text_field(:start_date, {:class => 'datepicker' }) %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    });
  });
</script>
```

This doesn't work and gives me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function

Comment: Have you add the JQuery UI in your script?

Comment: @liontass Yes, I added "jquery-ui-rails" gem and required it in app.js, app.css.

Comment: did you restart your server after adding the gems? :o